# Cloning objects in C#

Tags: c#, deep-copy, cloning

I defined next class with virtual properties:

```
public class Order: BaseEPharmObject
{
    public Order()
    {
    }

    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? Closed { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderResult OrderResult { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Shift Shift { get; set; }
    public virtual Order LinkedOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal TotalPayable { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

and trying to clone objects of that derived class. How to implement a deep copy right in the base class?

Comment: Do you want the deep copy to be an instance of the base class or an instance of a derived class?

Comment: this will work for you http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Deep%20Cloning&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your types are [serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) you could use [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx):

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is generally to serialize the instance and rehydrate it back as a new instance.  One way of doing this is described [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sd_surajit/cloning05032007012620AM/cloning.aspx).

My only caveat to the article is that don't implement this as `ICloneable` - this interface is deprecated and is confusing to callers of your class.  The best thing would be to move this implementation into a utility method and call it there.