# In C# what are our options to clone an object or copy its properties?

Tags: c#, oop, clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cloning objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp)

[So we have no standard definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200409/what-is-the-difference-between-copying-and-cloning) to differ *cloning* from *copying*, let's just assume here they're the same.

Seems like it is [very complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025890/is-there-a-much-better-way-to-create-deep-and-shallow-clones-in-c/8026574#8026574) to clone objects in C#. At least in contrast with, let's say, [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object). There are indeed [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp) different ways to [do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930433/apply-properties-values-from-one-object-to-another-of-the-same-type-automaticall). And it's even [argued it makes no sense copying objects](http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm).

That said, what are all our built-in options to do it? For instance, is there any [non-serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585652/methods-for-deep-cloning-objects-in-c-sharp) option which we wouldn't need to worry about [protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308803/why-is-cloning-in-net-so-difficult)?

And what are the common ways around to do it? Do we have names for them, like we have for [sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Summaries_of_popular_sorting_algorithms)?

Comment: now I'm confused ... isn't erverything you asked for already in the question you linked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp) - or do you want a 236 upvotes too? :D

Comment: What is being suggested in the javascript link is the same as what is being done in C# in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp.  The difference is that in JS all objects are serializable, whereas in C# they are not.  C# is a sharp tool, no pun intended: http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2006/10/31/my-programming-manifesto/

Comment: @CarstenKönig I want someone with (way more) experience to, at least, confirm that.

Comment: I rather you guys had closed it as off-topic or ill-formatted... This is far from duplicate and I pointed many links giving many different answers to this same broader subject, but I could find none pointing why there are so many options and what are the differences. I'm not asking how to do it.

Comment: @ChrisShain thanks for the insight! I never thought of C# being sharper than javascript... Aren't you mistaking this comparison with .NET versus browser script? After all, as far as I see, javascript definition does support metaprogramming along with many other amazing features. I haven't notice what you pointed about objects being serializiable in JS versus C# and it only makes me wonder even more if C# actually is so powerful as this manifesto or you may make it looks like. Nevertheless, thanks again for the insight! :-)

Comment: @Cawas I don't want to start a flame war- javascript is a very powerful language, and with the coverage it's received lately I am sure it's use will only continue to grow.  Think of it this way- I can haul stuff in a pickup truck, but I can't drive it very fast on a race track.  I can take a ferrari up to 200MPH on a track, but I can't carry lumber with it.  Each tool has it's uses and features, and it's your job to pick the right one for the job.

Comment: @ChrisShain sorry if it looked like flaming. I do dislike C# and sometimes I let the feeling show. But, as I asked, I'd still like to hear from you if you really meant JS vs C# and then I'm missing something I should research more or if you meant .NET versus browser script, to which I couldn't agree more. NET is way more resourceful in many ways and, using the car comparison, browser script is simply a cheaper volvo which will bring you from point A to B if you don't need speed on a track nor carrying lumber. :)

Comment: @CarstenKönig I just completely edited it. Still confused? You can downvote this for all I care... Or point me to another answered actual duplicated question and delete this. I just wanted to have a list of methods we can use to copy / clone objetcs.